# Create and Edit Android Studio New Project Template

Tags: android-studio

Where are steps for creating a user defined new project template, using Android Studio Hedgehog. Existing published solutions are obsolete and cannot be completed. If possible only using IntelliJ, not Android Studio, where are the steps for this? Thank you.